# Possible to store and use @AuthenticatedPrincipal after login

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, spring-security, socket.io

I have a *Spring-boot JavaFX 11 client* and [Feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/) (node) backend connected via websocket using [socket.io.client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java). I am able to establish connection, make request and so on but I was thinking if I am able to store the authenticated user information and retrieve using Spring-Security `@AuthenticatedPrincipal`.

For example,

```java
// JavaFX client, fill up the credential and login
@Service
public class UserService {
    @FXML
    public void login() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("strategy", "local");
        obj.put("email", "abc@xyz.com");
        obj.put("password", "password");
        
        socket.emit("create", "authentication", obj, onLogin());
    }

    private Ack onLogin() {
        return args -> {
          Auth auth;
          try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            auth = mapper.readValue(args[1].toString(), Auth.class);
            String prettyAuth = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(auth);
            System.out.println("prettyAuth" + prettyAuth);
            // store to @AuthenticatedPrincipal
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        };
    }
}

// So I will get back something like
{
  "accessToken" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MDI5NjM5ODAsImV4cCI6MTYwMzA1MDM4MCwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly95b3VyZG9tYWluLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6ImZlYXRoZXJzIiwic3ViIjoiNWY4YWIxMTU5OTMyY2QxYjZjZGM2MDZjIiwianRpIjoiMjA5ZThkZDItYzMyOS00YzdmLWE1NWYtM2UyMjc5Y2VlNDAxIn0.Es6Q2zM8UWYQqcWaBdY-7_jBxLH4zF2j-xxxxxx-xxx",
  "authentication" : {
    "strategy" : "local"
  },
  "user" : {
    "_id" : "5f8ab1159932cd1b6cdc606c",
    "isVerified" : "true",
    "__v" : "0",
    "email" : "abc@xyz.com",
    "createdAt" : 1602924821157,
    "updatedAt" : 1602924821157
  }
}
```

How can I store my user-info so that I can retrieve via `@AuthenticatedPrincipal` anytime I want it. For example...

```java
// Making a HTTP request
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken); // can grab the token via @AuthenticatedPrincipal?

// display profile
public String getMyProfile(@AuthenticatedPrincipal user) {
  return user.name;
}

// access control
@PreAuthorize("#username == authentication.principal.username")
public String getMyRoles(String username) {
    //...
}
```

I have read up quite a bit but don't quite understand how to use it in this case. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

Update:

Based on some additional research, I defined the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` right after I am authenticated.

```java
// this is done on `onLogin` right after
String prettyAuth = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(auth);
            System.out.println("prettyAuth" + prettyAuth);

Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getUser(), null,
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
System.out.println("authentication" + authentication);
```

And it looks great where I can get the `Authentication` object

```json
authenticationorg.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@818f7503: Principal: User(_id=5f8ab1159932cd1b6cdc606c, isVerified=true, __v=0, email=abc@xyz.com, createdAt=Sat Oct 17 16:53:41 SGT 2020, updatedAt=Sat Oct 17 16:53:41 SGT 2020); Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

But when I try to access the `Authentication` object from elsewhere,

```
System.out.println("Auth is" + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
```

I am getting a `null`, any idea?

---

Update:

I have figured out the cause of it.

```java
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getUser(), "password",
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

This is defined inside a `EventThread` so because it is bound to `ThreadLocal`, when I access it back on `ApplicationThread`, I get back a `null` context. I tried to set `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);` but it doesn't work which I think that it will work only if you have the `context` set before spawning another thread.

It works if I set to `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL);` but I not sure if it is ok to do so.. I thought it could be as this is a client application.

Comment: You can use `Authentication` class. Example `@GetMapping("/myprofie") public User getMyProfile(Authentication authentication) { User user = userService.getByUsername(authentication.getName()); return user; }`. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html

Comment: Hi @Seldo97, thanks but this is a JavaFX client. There is no web-service involved in my client. This JavaFX client only make API calls to nodejs backend. So in my client, there won't be any (at)GetMapping or anything like this.

Comment: I have updated post to reflect the issue after using `Authentication`, thanks